# Animated qtawesome icon does not repaint automatically

Tags: animation, pyqt, spyder, pyqt6

I have added an animated icon to a `QAction` which is in a `QToolBar` and a `QActionGroup`, but the animation is only re-drawn when the mouse enters / exits the widget area or when the window is resized. It would seem the underlying timer is continuing to function, as the rotation of the icon seems to be jumpy, but otherwise the correct speed when manually forcing the redraw with the mouse.

demo code and gif of behavior:

[image: demonstration of only re-drawing icon with user interaction]

```py
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt6' #for qtpy used by qtawesome

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import qtawesome as qta

class Main_App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()
        toolbar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
        action_group = QtGui.QActionGroup(toolbar)

        spin_widget = qta.IconWidget() #from qta demo
        spin_icon = qta.icon("mdi.loading", color="black", animation=qta.Spin(spin_widget))
        actionA = action_group.addAction(spin_icon, "A")
        toolbar.addAction(actionA)

        self.setCentralWidget(toolbar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app = Main_App()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec()
```

How do I get it to continuously update? Is `qtawesome` simply not compatible with `pyqt6` yet?

> versions:
>
> - python 3.11.3
> - pyqt6 6.5.0
> - qtawesome 1.2.3

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt6 compatibility, but with the fact that you're just adding an icon, which does not update itself automatically; you "connected" that icon to a widget, but that widget just gets destroyed because it's never used. Consider using QWidgetAction and return a proper QToolButton with the "animated icon" set for it from `createWidget()`.

Comment: @musicamante I think I was most confused about the utility of the widget passed to `qta.Spin`, as the timer it owned was clearly still running, so it was not GC'd, but perhaps because it was not added to any geometry manager, `update()` was being ignored. It seems I just needed to go find the correct widget to attach, as the demo on the qta readme didn't help (creating that template widget was copied directly)

Comment: It is actually a memory leak. `Spin()` creates a static reference to the given widget, but that should probably be a weakref, because if the widget is not kept alive by a real reference (instance attribute or Qt parent), it should be destroyed. Note that `update()` has no effect on the icon, but on the widget used as "parent" in the constructor. The other widget you were using to actually display the icon had no relation with that "parent", and that's why it didn't update the icon: widgets are buffered paint surfaces, they just get drawn once, unless updates are required.

Comment: So, the `_update()` was irrelevant, at least for the purpose of showing the animation. QIcons are actually strange objects: they are "passive" interfaces that just return pixmaps (or directly draw content with a given QPainter), but they cannot request an "update"; it's responsibility of the object that actually shows them to do that, and that's why you could only see changes when resizing: resizing a widget normally requires a full repaint of its whole area, and since the QTimer was still running (and updating the icon data), you were able to see the difference. In fact, you could have got ->

Comment: -> a similar result just by creating a QTimer for the returned `widgetForAction()` that would periodically call its `update()` slot: that would *not* have had direct effect on the icon, but just on the widget repainting, and since the icon timer was still alive, you'd have been able to see a "virtual" animation. I suggest you to file a bug report on the qtawesome project about this: while using a local as you did is discouraged, the same problem would happen for persistent widgets that get actually destroyed, for instance when used on a window with a `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was mixed up on the icon not being a widget itself, nor does an action contain a widget, and it is the widget associated with the action on the toolbar that must be passed to `qta.Spin`. I can access this value once the action has been added to the toolbar by `toolbar.widgetForAction(actionA)`. The code then becomes:

```py
import os
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt6' #for qtpy used by qtawesome

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import qtawesome as qta

class Main_App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()
        toolbar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical)
        action_group = QtGui.QActionGroup(toolbar)

        actionA = action_group.addAction("A") #create the action without an icon
        toolbar.addAction(actionA) #add the action to the toolbar before setting the icon because we need the widget created here
        
        spin_icon = qta.icon("mdi.loading", color="black", animation=qta.Spin(toolbar.widgetForAction(actionA)))
        actionA.setIcon(spin_icon)

        self.setCentralWidget(toolbar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app = Main_App()
    app.show()
    qapp.exec()
```